# How to have optional peer dependency using and in Join's

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, joi

I have a joi schema in such a way:

```
joi.object({
  a: joi.string(),
  b: joi.string(),
  c: joi.string()
}).and('a', 'b').and('b', 'c');
```

I want it to be such that any "one" of the `and` pairs runs successfully, i.e. if 'a' is provided 'b' should be there, if 'c' is provided 'b' should be there, and if 'b' is provided, 'a' or 'c' should be there.

Comment: Are you looking for any combination of two parameters or exactly as you've listed?